# How do I change the datepicker year dropdown list to be smaller in height? It's really long and extends towards the start/end of the viewport

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

The height is quite long for a dropdown list of the years. I've tried using CSS but to no avail, I think it requires more than that. I've been searching online and can't seem to find the right answer, and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for in the documentation.

Comment: can you post some code pls.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to reduce the height of a select element's list via CSS.

You can use the `yearRange` option to set the range of years to be displayed though if you want to reduce the number of options. For example 2016-2021:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker("option", "yearRange", "2016:2021");
```

More info in the documentation: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange